# Spring Data (JPARepository) does not return result

Tags: java, spring-data

My SpringData version is **1.10.4.RELEASE**.
I have Scaffolding Repository extends JPARepository like below

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IScaffoldingDAO<DATA> extends JpaRepository<DATA, Long>, ITransactionDAO<DATA, Long>, IInquiryDAO<DATA, Long>{

    public List<DATA> findByCode(String p_Code) throws DAOExeption;

    public List<DATA> findByName(String p_Name) throws DAOExeption;
}
```

And implementation Repository like below

```
public interface IMerchandiseTypeDAO extends IScaffoldingDAO<MerchandiseType>{
```

}

Then my service do autowiring to IMerchandiseTypeDAO like below

```
@Service("serviceBean")
public class class ScaffoldingServiceImpl<MerchandiseType> implements
        IScaffoldingService<MerchandiseType>, IServiceInitializer {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScaffoldingServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    IMerchandiseTypeDAO merchandiseTypeDAO;

    @Override
    public List<MerchandiseType> findByCode(String p_Code) {
        try {
            List<MerchandiseType> results = merchandiseTypeDAO.findByCode(p_Code);
            LOGGER.info("MerchandiseType Size : "+results.size());
            return results;
        } catch (DAOExeption e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, i don't get any result from method findByCode even though my hibernate query run well on my sql editor.

Following is my Log :

```
Hibernate: select merchandis0_.id as id1_3_, merchandis0_.created_by as created_2_3_, merchandis0_.created_ip as created_3_3_, merchandis0_.created_platform as created_4_3_, merchandis0_.created_time as created_5_3_, merchandis0_.modified_by as modified6_3_, merchandis0_.modified_ip as modified7_3_, merchandis0_.modified_platform as modified8_3_, merchandis0_.modified_time as modified9_3_, merchandis0_.remarks as remarks10_3_, merchandis0_.status as status11_3_, merchandis0_.code as code12_3_, merchandis0_.name as name13_3_ from mst_merchandise_type merchandis0_ where merchandis0_.code=?

MerchandiseType Size : 0
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Your query looks correct, check the received parameter code and try the query with sql editor.

Comment: I've been checking the received parameter. everything looks alright. Then i try with SQL Editor. it works. So, what next i should do ?

Comment: `LOGGER.info("received code : "+p_code);` add this before calling dao method.